# Can we get to know Browser rendering time for each page in JMeter using webDriver sampler?

Tags: selenium, jmeter, webdriver, rendering

I am planning to do a load test with around 220 users ,Client is expecting Browser rendering time as well. So I though 1 will create one script for load test ,and create one more script with Selenium script in JMeter to measure rendering time. So that while executing load test , if I execute selenium script as well. It will give the Browser rendering time.
But as I saw, With Selenium sampler ,Aggregate report shows end to end response time. If i want to know the Browser rendering time of each page ,if there any way to get the breakdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Use a separate WebDriver Sampler per "page" like:

   [image]
2. Alternatively you can use [`WDS.sampleResult.addSubResult` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#addSubResult-org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult-) to add "child" results to a single WebDriver Sampler instance, example code would be something like:

   ```
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
   var seleniumDev = new org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult()
   seleniumDev.setSampleLabel('Selenium main page')
   seleniumDev.sampleStart()
   WDS.browser.get('https://selenium.dev')
   seleniumDev.setResponseCodeOK()
   seleniumDev.setSuccessful(true)
   seleniumDev.sampleEnd()
   WDS.sampleResult.addSubResult(seleniumDev)

   var jmeter = new org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult()
   jmeter.setSampleLabel('JMeter main page')
   jmeter.sampleStart()
   WDS.browser.get('https://jmeter.apache.org')
   jmeter.setResponseCodeOK()
   jmeter.setSuccessful(true)
   jmeter.sampleEnd()
   WDS.sampleResult.addSubResult(jmeter)

   WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
   ```

   resulting in the following:

   [image]

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)